# How can I use Base64 image paths in AppleScript?

Tags: base64, applescript

I have come up with an AppleScript, to monitor my VPN connection from VPN Tracker. So far I got the code working, meaning it shows the correct state as text. I created two PNG files, which I converted into Base64 and would like to use those as the status output, instead of just having text. The reason for the Base64 conversion of the images is, so I can share the script with others, without needing to share the actual images as well and expect the user to put them somewhere on his Mac.

I am however unsure of how to decode those Base64 strings in AppleScript, so it shows the actual image in the end.

This is the code I have so far (with the text output)

```js
set conn_state to "" as string

if application "VPN Tracker 365" is running then
    tell application "VPN Tracker 365"
        try
            if name of groups contains "group_name" then
                set conn_state to state of connection of group ("group_name") as string
                if conn_state = "On" then
                    return "VPN active"
                else
                    return "VPN inactive"
                end if
            end if
        on error
            return "An error occured"
        end try
    end tell
end if
```

I did do some research on the internet but could not find anything that would help me, solve this problem, or I was maybe not using the right search terms.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"The reason for the Base64 conversion of the images is, so I can share the script with others, without needing to share the actual images as well and expect the user to put them somewhere on his Mac."*

Consider taking a different approach. The following solution will enable the image(s) to be bundled within your Applescript and avoid having to Base64 encode/decode them:

1. Save your AppleScript as an *"Application"* format via the *AppleScript Editor*.
2. Locate your resultant application via the *"Finder"*

   - Click on it while pressing the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.
   - Via the context menu choose *"Show Package Contents"*.
3. Copy your `.png` image(s) to the `Contents/Resources` folder.
4. Then in your code access the path to the image as follows:

   ```
   # Get the pathname to where this script resides in the filesyetem.
   set pathToMe to (path to me) as text

   # Create the full pathname to the image 
   set pathToPng to pathToMe & "Contents:Resources:img.png" as alias

   # Just a demo to illustrate that the image path can be accessed.
   tell application "Preview" to open pathToPng
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** This example code assumes you've copied an image named `img.png` to the `Contents/Resources` folder. It firstly obtains the path to wherever your app is located and assigns the images path to the `pathToPng` variable</sub>

---

**Edit:**

Or, as [@user3439894](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439894/user3439894) kindly mentioned in the comments, simply use the following code to obtain the path to the image(s) directly:

```
# Create the full pathname to the image
set pathToPng to path to resource "img.png"

# Just a demo to illustrate that the image path can be accessed.
tell application "Preview" to open pathToPng
```

<sub>**Note:** This utilizes [`path to resource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW20) to obtain the path of the image, and the aforementioned steps 1-3 are still necessary</sub>

Comment: Why not use just [`path to resource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW20), e.g. `path to resource "img.png"`, then you do not need to first ascertain where the _application bundle_ is and then concatenate, as this returns the _fully qualified pathname_ as an _alias_.